# SQL select statement to Exclude a column from being sorted

Tags: sql, sorting, select

I am looking for a way to exclude a single column from being sorted using SQL select statement.

---

Lets say a table has 10 columns and when an ORDER BY is done on a specific column using select statement, all the 10 columns are sorted. Is it possible to exclude any specific column (say column 6) from being sorted? If so how.

**

Before

```
ID    name
-----------
1    papaya
2    apple
3    strawberry
4    banana
```

Required

```
ID    name
-----------
1    apple
2    banana
3    papaya
4    strawberry
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Exclude from sorting? Just don't put this column in your order statement?!

Comment: He means Id should be there,

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all - you cannot detach values from their rows :) Why would you want that?

Comment: Further: Both cannot be sorted like 1=apple (or 1=papaya). ID is always the same for papaya (resp. apple)

Comment: ID should be there but not to be sorted

Comment: `Select * from TABLE order by NAME`?

Comment: Agree. But i have a different column in the table which is the actual id. like 001, 002 etc which is tagged to 001 (apple), 002 (banana) etc. This ID shown in the post is the one which doesnt require to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate the ids and they will be always shown in order but that won't be the actual id, you might need that as well

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 id,name from tableName order by name
```